# Content projection / transclusion without using containing elements

Tags: angular

I'm trying to transclude some content inside a component (`<parent>`) with multiple `<ng-content>` slots **without using a containing element for the child**.

I need to do this because the layout inside the parent uses **flexbox**, and I specifically want to leverage the power of flexbox for this particular use-case. Unfortunately with flexbox it works on the direct children, so the containing element is causing problems.

Here is my pseudo parent template. It is using Bootstrap 4 with flexbox enabled.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs">
        Heading
        <ng-content select="[anotherSlot]"></ng-content>
    </div>
    <ng-content select="[child]"></ng-content>
</div>
```

Then is this what I am doing when I use the component. For simplicity's sake I'm not showing the `[anotherSlot]` in use, but it is a requirement.

I have tried the @Directive approach, using `[child]`

```
<parent>
    <div child>
        <div class="col-xs-2">Small section</div>
        <div class="col-xs">This should fill the available space</div>
    </div>
</parent>
```

But then my transcluded content is wrapped in a `<div child>`, so that breaks the flexbox layout.

It renders like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs">
        Heading
    </div>
    <div> <!-- This div is the problem -->
        <div class="col-xs-2">Small section</div>
        <div class="col-xs">This should fill the available space</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've also tried the @Component approach:

```
<parent>
    <child>
        <div class="col-xs-2">Small section</div>
        <div class="col-xs">This should fill the available space</div>
    </child>
</parent>
```

But that results in this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs">
        Heading
    </div>
    <child> <!-- This is still a problem -->
        <div class="col-xs-2">Small section</div>
        <div class="col-xs">This should fill the available space</div>
    </child>
</div>
```

**How can I achieve this?** The first `<div>` is static, but the others will vary depending on the use.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs">
        Heading
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        Small section
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs">
        This should fill the available space
    </div>
</div>
```

Can I use `<template>` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok figured it out.

It turns out that `<ng-content>` can handle multiple items.

So using the @Directive approach I can do this:

```
<parent>
    <div class="col-xs-2" child>Small section</div>
    <div class="col-xs" child>This should fill the available space</div>
</parent>
```

And it results in this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs">
        Heading
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        Small section
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs">
        This should fill the available space
    </div>
 </div>
```

Obvious really!

Comment: I'm not sure it's that obvious, thanks for documenting this here!